# What's an alternative to using ObjectId as a unique identifier for a user in mongo?

Tags: mongodb, collections, userid, bigdata

My site layout is like so:

```
blah.com/user/<username>

User1 {
  _id: "ObjectID(asdfa)",
  name: "john smith",
  email: "blah@test.com,
  friends: [
    "ObjectID(asdfa2)",
    "ObjectID(asdfa3)",
    "ObjectID(asdfa4)",
  ]
}
```

I would rather not use the username as the unique key in my collection so I want to use an ID. But I dont think it would be good to have ObjectID references everywhere. How do I go about making an organized collection where the _id is both unique and readable, without auto-increment?

Comment: Why do you think it would not be good? There's nothing wrong with ObjectIDs.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14277486/125816

Comment: I saw it in a question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697631/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-a-mongo-objectid-as-a-users-id

Comment: A unique, efficient, readable ID is a tall order in MongoDB especially as it doesn't have an auto-increment column. If your `usernames` are unique, and never change, that seems like a reasonable alternative.

Comment: I would say that usernames are not a good choice, just like objectids on a shard the alphabet is a monotonic figure (a-z) just like the timestamp of the objectid which is what can make it bad for certain situations. Due to this you could be seeing all new writes become unbalanced within the cluster and sent to a single shard. This is not always a bad thing but it is something you need to bare in mind. Another alternative is GUIDs which are much more "random". You can hash your shard key to create balance.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, literature recommends try natural keys, but as I can see, your collection there is no meaningful value, except email, but it is usually sensitive data.

You can generate a key on application layer based on any business rule you define and avoid auto increment keys and add some meaning to the key used in your system URLs.

Regards,
Moacy